# Create SIP URI for phone number

Tags: twilio, sip, opentok

I am new to SIP URL, i want to initiate a call from admin portal to user phone number, for this i took some reference from opentok and twilio but it ask me to set SIP URL, so is there any site from where i can create SIP URI for phone number

Comment: Which documentation are you referencing? You need to provide more details. A SIP URI is a destination you would basically dial. Is the person you are calling on a SIP device or are you planning to send the call to a SIP service provider that will forward that call onto the telephone network (PSTN)?

Comment: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/sip/#intro-to-sip this document i am referring

Comment: Is this the piece you are most interested in? `Customers must set up a SIP-PSTN gateway for this purpose.`. If so, you will be looking at this on Twilio - Inbound - Sending SIP to Twilio - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sending-sip, then forwarding the call to the PSTN - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding.

Comment: @Alan i want send the call to a sip service that will forward that call into the PSTN